# Swift: How to let a webview reload its url

Tags: swift, button, webview, refresh, reload

I have a app with a website. On the website there are links to other sites and pages of the website but how can I reload the page with a button or a tabbar that it goes back to the main page from the webview

Answer (score 8):

You can simply create two button, one to goes back and one to refresh and then connect these `IBActions`:

```
  @IBAction func doRefresh(AnyObject) {
    webView.reload()
  }

  @IBAction func goBack(AnyObject) {
    webView.goBack()
  }
```

Comment: But I mean a button that go back to the main page of the webview.

Comment: webview dont have a "main page", it's a client to show a page or a list of page, this depend by you. You can organize a list of page in an array and force to go to the first element.